# Design Pattern for storing most requested images in a map object

Tags: java, tomcat, design-patterns

I have a website that lets users generate an image. I then provide an embed link 
which they can paste on their blog/website. The link conists of a simple html img 
element which calls and then returns the image from my webapp to their website.

Currently, I'm reading the image from the file system and returning it via 
the response outputstream.

My question is, is there a better more efficient way of doing this? I mostly would like 
to keep the top 10 images in memory for faster access.

I currently have a singleton object that stores some data during app startup. My idea was to create a Map/List object and then store the image bytes in there. My images have unique names so that should make it a bit simpler.

I'd imagnie I'd need to store the image name, the last time accessesed, frequencey accessed and then kick out the images that were last accessed or have low times accessed.

I'd rather not re-invent the wheel if there is already a design pattern for this. Anyone ever implement something similar? Any general idea of what is the best way to implement this would be helpful.

I use Tomact 7, Java 7

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a caching library.

Check out:

- [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/)
- [Commons JCS](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/index.html)
- [EHCache](http://ehcache.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Did you already take a look to the [Guava-Libraries from Google](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)? You can find a LoadingCache there, which maybe makes exactly what you want. Look at the [CachesExplained Wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained).